# Why can't I inflate my Fragments in Android?

Tags: android, fragment

I have an activity that would contain three fragments two having `listView` layouts and one that have a `Relative layout`.

Here is the xml for the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id = "@+id/activity_main_large"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

     <fragment
         android:id="@+id/menu_category_fragment"
         android:name="com.thesis.menubook.MenuCategory"
         android:layout_width="123dp"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         tools:layout="@layout/activity_menu_category" />

     <fragment
         android:id="@+id/menu_fragment"
         android:name="com.thesis.menubook.MenuFragment"
         android:layout_width="0dip"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_weight="0.35"
         tools:layout="@layout/activity_menu_fragment" />

     <fragment
         android:id="@+id/orderlist_fragment"
         android:name="com.thesis.menubook.OrderListFragment"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_weight="0.08"
         tools:layout="@layout/activity_order_list" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the java file for the Main Activity

```
package com.thesis.menubook;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MenuMain extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

There so I am just trying to load empty fragments to see if they would actually load and then add the widgets and codes to import data into the fragments. But I am getting an Error saying `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.thesis.menubook/com.thesis.menubook.MenuMain}:`

Is there anything I am overlooking that is why it cannot load empty fragments?

Here is my LogCat (updated after correcting the class names):

```
02-12 23:04:28.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1143): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-12 23:04:28.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1143): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.thesis.menubook/com.thesis.menubook.MenuMain}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
02-12 23:04:28.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1748)
02-12 23:04:28.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1764)
02-12 23:04:28.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)
02-12 23:04:28.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1002)
02-12 23:04:28.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-12 23:04:28.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
02-12 23:04:28.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
02-12 23:04:28.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-12 23:04:28.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
02-12 23:04:28.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
02-12 23:04:28.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
02-12 23:04:28.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-12 23:04:28.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1143): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
02-12 23:04:28.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:688)
02-12 23:04:28.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:724)
02-12 23:04:28.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
02-12 23:04:28.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:391)
02-12 23:04:28.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:347)
02-12 23:04:28.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:223)
02-12 23:04:28.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1780)
02-12 23:04:28.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at com.thesis.menubook.MenuMain.onCreate(MenuMain.java:15)
02-12 23:04:28.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
02-12 23:04:28.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1712)
02-12 23:04:28.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     ... 11 more
02-12 23:04:28.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1143): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.thesis.menubook.MenuCategory cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment
02-12 23:04:28.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:493)
02-12 23:04:28.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:468)
02-12 23:04:28.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4132)
02-12 23:04:28.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:664)
02-12 23:04:28.369: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     ... 20 more
02-12 23:04:28.905: D/dalvikvm(1143): GC_CONCURRENT freed 329K, 6% free 7390K/7815K, paused 12ms+20ms
02-12 23:04:34.180: I/Process(1143): Sending signal. PID: 1143 SIG: 9**
```

MenuCategory.java

```
package com.thesis.menubook;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MenuCategory extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_menu_category, container, false);
            return view;
    }
}
```

MenuFragment.java

```
package com.thesis.menubook;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MenuFragment extends Fragment{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_menu_fragment, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

OrderListFragment.java

```
package com.thesis.menubook;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class OrderListFragment extends Fragment{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_order_list, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Here are the xml files for the fragments :

activity_menu_category

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


</ListView>
```

activity_menu_fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:gravity="bottom|top" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:paddingLeft="16dp" android:paddingRight="16dp" android:paddingTop="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
        android:paddingTop="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_order_list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Name Label -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/categoryname"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong Fragment class. You are using the support library fragments `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.  And it expects the native framework implementation: `android.app.Fragment`.

If you want to use the support library, to enable use on older versions, your activity needs to extend `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`.  Then you would use the `getSupportFragmentManager()` method to get the FragmentManager and add your fragments.

Comment: amazing. All the other answers miss the point completely and give some generic advice. This one is spot on - and yet it's the last one and was not even upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your answer

```
Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.android.fragments.MenuCategory: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
```

Make sure you have default/empty `public` constructor in `MenuCategory` and also make sure that `MenuCategory` is not an inner class, if it is then it should be `public` and `static`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `MenuCategory`, `MenuFragment`, `OrderListFragment` classes in your project? And if so do you have them in a package called `com.example.android.fragments` ? If you have those classes, but you put them in your own package you'll need to change the package name in the xml layout to your own instead of the com.example one.

Comment: I do have them in my project. SO will I need to make a new folder and name it as such then put them in the said folder?

Comment: you could do that, but you should instead just change `com.example.android.fragments` to `com.thesis.menubook` in your layout xml file.

Comment: I saw them in the xml file and changed them but it still has the same error

Comment: where are the classes at in your project? are they in your main package? `com.thesis.menubook` ?

Comment: Don't I have to put .java after MenuCategory?

Comment: post your code for `MenuCategory` class does it have `extends Fragment` on it? it needs to if not.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is right there in the error message:

Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.android.fragments.MenuCategory

You need to have, in your project, a class whose fully qualified name is com.example.android.fragments.MenuCategory, that is a subclass of Fragment, and that has a no-args constructor

Edited to add:

In the tag in your layout:

```
<fragment
         android:id=blah blah blah
         android:name="com.thesis.menubook.MenuCategory"
```

... you name a Java class.  In your example, it is "com.thesis.menubook.MenuCategory".  As I said, that class must exist in your project, extend Fragment, and have a no-args constructor (in fact, you should not give in any constructor at all, so that it has only its default constructor). For each fragment tag, you must have such a class, corresponding to the value of each android:name attribute.

Comment: I changed it to com.thesis.menubook.MenuCategory and it still has the same error

Answer (score 0):

1) You should change the value of minSdkVersion to 11 in Anroidmanifest.xml.
2) Check whether the name value of fragment defined in your mainactivity.xml is correct, i.e packagename.Fragmentclassname.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was something else, i was using navigation component, and it happen that i didn't add the`id` of the fragment tag, also be sure to upgrade to the latest gradle version ( mine is `3.3.2` for the moment )